# Saving data in a view pager

Tags: android, save, android-viewpager

I have a view pager to display some editable items in it. When the user edits the items, i need to save them, in order to show them again when the user opens the said screen again.
I'ved tried putting the save routine inside the "saveState" method, however, that method never gets called

in which method can i save the data i need ?

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "destroyItem "+position);
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    Log.d(TAG, "isViewFromObject");
    return view == ((View) object);
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "finishUpdate");
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
    Log.d(TAG, "restoreState");
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    Log.d(TAG, "saveState");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void startUpdate(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "startUpdate");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer - it is "in any method in the activity that governs the viewpager"

there is no need to save the state of the views, there is a need to save t he state of the data, as the state of the data is what determines how the views will look like.
any change to the data should be saved in the activity in which the pager was opened.